# Change Background Color of div through submit form?

Tags: css, selector

Was a bit unsure how else to word this, JavaScript is the main thing I NEED to learn but after putting hours and hours in i still can't write javascript code off the top of my head. I understand the syntax of just about everything but when it comes to integrating it with css or html I am clueless!

Heres the code:

HTML:

`<div id="mydiv">
  <input type="text" name="colorpicker">
  <input type="submit" value="Submit">
</div>`

JavaScript:

```
document.getElementById("mydiv").style.backgroundColor="colorpicker.Submit";
```

bare in mind i've had little experience with forms and inputs in html too.

Any reply would be much appriciated! Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The value for `style.backgroundColor` should be a string representing a color value used in CSS, which can be one of:

- Color name such as red, green, pink, ...
- Color hex code such as #ff0000 (or #f00), #00ff00, #ff00ff ...
- rgb() or rgba() function such as rgb(255,0,0), rgb(0,255,0), ...

You also have to set up the click event handler for the button submit.  Here are details:

**HTML**:

```
<div id="mydiv">
  <input type="text" name="colorpicker"/>
  <input type="submit" value="Submit"/>
</div>
```

**JS**:

```
var div = document.getElementById('mydiv');
div.children[1].onclick = function(){
   div.style.backgroundColor = div.children[0].value;
};
```

Note that you can assign an id for each input field to get access to it in JS code, in the above code I use the `children` collection to access to them instead. The first input field is the first child of `div`, the second input field is the second child of `div`.

### [Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/SnSLk/)

Also note that, since HTML5 (which has been supported by all the major browsers) you can use the color input field which can popup a real color picker dialog for the user to select and then you just need to handle the event `onchange` to get the selected color (via the `value` property) like this:

**HTML**:

```
<div id="mydiv">
  <input type="color" name='colorpicker'/>    
</div>
```

**JS**:

```
var div = document.getElementById('mydiv');
div.children[0].onchange = function(){
  div.style.backgroundColor = div.children[0].value;
};
```

### [Updated Demo.](http://jsfiddle.net/SnSLk/1/)

Comment: That's perfect dude! Thanks for this, I'd like to give that onchange event a go, I'll try working out where to put it.

Answer (score 0):

Use the form tag onsubmit method to call your JavaScript function.